# How to install Gostcrypt in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, 17.10

I'm trying to install Gostcrypt in ubuntu 17.10 using this package : https://www.gostcrypt.org/download.php

But there is a dependency error `libwxbase2.8-dev` and when i try to install it there's another dependency error `wx2.8-headers` i installed them but there's allways another dependency error.

I also try to `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev pkg-config`

`libwxgtk2.8-dev` won't install also

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Yes, and no. A software that was last released 6 years ago is definitely deprecated, so you should NOT install it. The solution is to find an alternative that it is still maintained (what does this software do and why do you want to install exactly this software and not something current?) and install it.

Comment: Gostcrypt was a good alternative to truecrypt with russian algorithm before veracrypt and i have a usb key encrypted with Gostcrypt ^^ ... perhap's need to install a virtual machine of ubuntu 16.04 to get back my files

Comment: Neither ubuntu16.04 nor debian works to install Gostcrypt in virtual machines. I contacted the developer of the application to inform him about dependencys errors and send him link to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i understand that Veracrypt is the best way to crypt files with Ubuntu 18.04 and more. Veracrypt is trust workable app during in time. Ghostscript is really outdated. Everybody should replace ghostscript with verascript.